# Bigquery Split with comma in data

Tags: google-bigquery

Below is my source table, need expected result but getting incorrect result for the below query. Please help

[image]

Query :

select
ID,
metric,
value
from (
SELECT
*,
REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(0)], r'^"|"$', '') metric,
REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(1)], r'^"|"$', '') value
FROM
,
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(to_json_string(), r'{|}', ''))) pair
)
where metric not in (ID)
order by metric, value;

Expected result:

[image: ID metric value 100 digits 890908,890909,890910, 890911]

incorrect result with above query:

[image]

Comment: data and code example you provided makes no much sense - can you rather explain the logic you are trying to implement. and obviously make sure that input data and expected result is correctly presented as it looks like not as of now!

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see there is no need to touch the Value column as you only add a column named "metric"

I would suggest working with an Case statement

Answer (score 0):

The source is having dynamic columns. Hence, we can't hard code any columns except ID.